# serving gziped files only - a good idea?

Tags: gzip

I have a web service that serves widgets. For scalability sake I want to keep gzipped versions of the js files on Amazon S3. The thing is that browswers not able to accept gzipped files will not be served.

Anyone know where I can find statistics to know how many of the potential users will not be served? Is it a good idea in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[See this page from the `mod_gzip` pages.](http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/browser.htm) It has a breakdown of which browsers support what.

Comment: Well, it's a bit dated, but you get the idea. There is *very* good support in every modern browser for gzip compressed files.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is a good idea - as far as I know all modern browsers accept gzipped content. One thing you can do to prevent older browsers from being served gzipped content is to tell the web server to not gzip the output for such browsers. Here's an apache example (excerpt from a .htaccess):

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application
/x-javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. My question is not related to using gzip normally by a server that can serve both gzipped and non gzipped version according to the browser. My question is about serving only gzipped versions, so browsers withoug gzip support will not get served.